# python generator thread safety using Keras

Tags: python, generator

I am using Keras for some ML and have this generator for the data and labels:

```
def createBatchGenerator(driving_log,batch_size=32):
    batch_images = np.zeros((batch_size, 66, 200, 3))
    batch_steering = np.zeros(batch_size)
    while 1:
        for i in range(batch_size):
            x,y = get_preprocessed_row(driving_log)
            batch_images[i]=x
            batch_steering[i]=y
        yield batch_images, batch_steering
```

When I use it locally it runs fine, but when I run it on an AWS g2.2xlarge with a GPU, I get this error "ValueError: generator already executing". Can someone please help me resolve this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need to make a [generator that can support multi-threading](http://anandology.com/blog/using-iterators-and-generators/) to make sure the generator is called by two threads at once:

```
import threading

class createBatchGenerator:

    def __init__(self, driving_log,batch_size=32):
        self.driving_log = driving_log
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.lock = threading.Lock()

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        with self.lock:
           batch_images = np.zeros((batch_size, 66, 200, 3))
           batch_steering = np.zeros(batch_size)

           for i in range(self.batch_size):
               x,y = get_preprocessed_row(self.driving_log)
               batch_images[i]=x
               batch_steering[i]=y
           return batch_images, batch_steering
```

Comment: Got this working in Python 3.5 after importing threading `import threading`, adding `self.lock = threading.Lock()` in the `def __init__` and renaming `def next` to `def __next__`.

Comment: @tuomastik I updated my answer to include your changes.  Thanks for posting them.

Comment: @RickSmith Thanks, could you please add an example of usage of this generator, how to get samples/images from it